# Obnoxious usage and meaning

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

When should one use the word "obnoxious"  , with what intension one should use it and how offensive this word is?

My question is when to use this word and by this I mean to whom I can say this word can I say this to my cousin how is making fun of me or being hard on me or just annoying me for couple of hour . Is it OK to say him/her obnoxious or is it too offensive statement to make.

Comment: What does the dictionary say, and how is it unclear to you? Please [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: @200_success - Aside from occasional labels like `vulgar` or `obscene`, dictionaries aren't very good about putting words on an offensiveness scale. [Here's a pretty good dictionary link for this word](https://wordnik.com/words/obnoxious) – but, if I were a learner, I still wouldn't know if this would be considered inappropriate to use in front of my cousin.

Answer (score 4):

It is perfectly acceptable to tell someone

> **Stop being so obnoxious!
>
>   Why are you being obnoxious?**

often followed by

> **Stop it!
>
>   Go away!
>
>   Leave me alone!**

The word **obnoxious** is itself not offensive, but can be used to describe behaviour, actions or words that are offensive.

Answer (score 1):

The word obnoxious is actually a synonym of the word [objectionable](http://www.aamboli.com/translate/objectionable) (an adjective) and is defined as:

> causing disapproval or protest

Though the word sounds rude, and is often believed to be so; you could actually use it without being too rude.

As to when should you use this word? You could use it when you disapprove of an event in either disgust or in discomfort.

And lastly, yes it is really ok to call your cousin obnoxious, except if you call him/her obnoxious in totality. In that case it would be rude. You may call him/her obnoxious under a particular event eg.

> Your behaviour last evening was obnoxious